# AxiosError: Network Error in React Native Expo development build

Tags: react-native, networking, axios, expo, backend

I'm encountering an issue specific to my React Native Expo development build. I have multiple APIs in my application, and while most of them work without any issues, I'm consistently getting an **`AxiosError: Network Error`** when trying to make a request to one particular API but that one particular API is working fine in postman.

I am running my project only in Android Real device

Here are some details about the issue:

- Environment: React Native Expo development build
- Issue: Only occurs with one specific API, other APIs work fine
- Error message: **`AxiosError: Network Error`**
- API : http://myIP:8080/api/v1/post/deal-posts
- Request method: [POST]

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbVsl.png)
this is my console error picture

this below is my network header
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyxPf.png)

this is my code

```
const handleDealPost = async () => {
    try {
      const titleInFilename = title.replace(/\s+/g, "_");
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const formattedDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString().replace(/-/g, "");
      const imageKey = `${titleInFilename}_${formattedDate}.jpg`;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("dealURL", dealURL);
      formData.append("title", title);
      formData.append("company", company);
      formData.append("discountedPrice", discountedPrice);
      formData.append("originalPrice", originalPrice);
      formData.append("description", description);
      formData.append("category", category);
      formData.append("dealType", dealType);
      formData.append("image", {
        uri: image.uri,
        type: image.type,
        name: imageKey,
      });
      formData.append("expiryDate", expiryDate.toString());

      // console.log("FormData:", formData);

      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://MyIp:8080/api/v1/post/deal-posts",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      const result = response.data;
      if (response.status === 201) {
        Alert.alert("Success", result.message);
        setPosts([...posts, result?.post]);
        // navigation.navigate("BottomTabsNavigator");
        navigation.navigate("Home");
        setDealURL("");
        setTitle("");
        setCompany("");
        setDiscountedPrice("");
        setOriginalPrice("");
        setDescription("");
        setCategory(null);
        setDealType(null);
        setImage(null);
        setExpiryDate("");
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Error", result.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "An error occurred while posting the deal");
    }
  };
```

- Checked API endpoint
- Tested the API endpoint with tools like Postman[working fine]
- I've tested with other APIs in the same development build, and they work without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add type:  in the value of the formData

For Example:

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("myImage", {
    uri: "myFileURI",
    name: "myfileName",
    **type: "image/jpeg"**, //  Add this!!!!!!!
})
```